# certbot renow nginx not resart but site work

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl-certificate

I have a website to ubuntu 16.04 and i use certbot to my certificat ssl and when a run this commande

```
certbot renew --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start" --force-renewal
```

i have i big problem the certificat as been renew but nginx will not restart but my website and the certificat work perfectly. when i go to my website i have no bug but ngnix is not start and a not have apache

when i tap this `systemctl status nginx.service`

if have this errors

```
    Dec 24 09:00:06 jobs nginx[13997]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 24 09:00:06 jobs nginx[13997]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 24 09:00:07 jobs nginx[13997]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 24 09:00:07 jobs nginx[13997]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 24 09:00:07 jobs nginx[13997]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 24 09:00:07 jobs nginx[13997]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Dec 24 09:00:07 jobs systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 24 09:00:07 jobs systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Dec 24 09:00:07 jobs systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 24 09:00:07 jobs systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

i try  [Can't restart nginx, bind() failed (98: Address already in use)](https://serverfault.com/questions/675526/cant-restart-nginx-bind-failed-98-address-already-in-use) but is not work