# Nginx stops unknowingly with error bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

We are running a node js application with Nginx as a reverse proxy in demo and prod server.

Nginx has been stopped unknowingly with the below error. I login to the server and simply start nginx manually `sudo service nginx start` and **it starts successfully**. But still could not find out the root cause for the shutdown. This occurred twice in demo server and thanks god not in prod server so far.

```
2018/04/05 12:44:03 [notice] 20030#20030: signal process started
2018/04/06 00:35:49 [notice] 23507#23507: signal process started
2018/04/06 12:08:18 [notice] 25473#25473: signal process started
2018/04/06 12:08:18 [error] 25473#25473: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2018/04/06 12:08:20 [notice] 25479#25479: signal process started
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/04/06 12:08:22 [emerg] 25514#25514: still could not bind()
2018/04/06 12:08:24 [alert] 25475#25475: unlink() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2018/04/07 00:02:58 [notice] 28369#28369: signal process started
2018/04/07 00:02:58 [error] 28369#28369: invalid PID number "" in "/run/nginx.pid"
2018/04/07 12:12:44 [notice] 30352#30352: signal process started
2018/04/07 12:12:44 [error] 30352#30352: invalid PID number "" in "/run/nginx.pid"
2018/04/08 00:43:19 [notice] 811#811: signal process started
2018/04/08 00:43:19 [error] 811#811: invalid PID number "" in "/run/nginx.pid"
```

As per the [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/675526/cant-restart-nginx-bind-failed-98-address-already-in-use), it says the about problem when restarting, but in my case it shutdowns automatically.

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972792/nginx-nginx-emerg-bind-to-80-failed-98-address-already-in-use), it suggests adding `ipv6only=on` to `[::]:80`, but the below is what the nginx default file has from the installation and I have added nginx config for node js as per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015178/1747111)

default server config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
```

vhost config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name demo.api.example.com;
```

**Additional Clarification Needed**

I think `20030#20030: signal process started` refers to nginx reload. Why does nginx reload twice daily? Is it anything to do with Nginx Amplify Agent or it's nginx's default behavior?

**Server Details:**

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- Nginx: nginx/1.10.3
- Additional Tools: Nginx Amplify Agent, PM2 2.9.2

Comment: Check the following link. This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972792/nginx-nginx-emerg-bind-to-80-failed-98-address-already-in-use

Comment: Check with the following link. It may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972792/nginx-nginx-emerg-bind-to-80-failed-98-address-already-in-use

Comment: Earlier nginx stopped unexpectedly on occasion. Now the occurrence has been increased. It is happening daily twice. Tried the above commented solution also. Still stops unexpectedly with the log as mentioned in question :(

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Looking for an answer.

Comment: @SukhjinderSingh I tried the mentioned solution and even commented the ipv6 line entirely. Still nginx shutdowns daily twice. I'm manually starting nginx every 12 hours.

Comment: I've the same problem, looks like nginx stops for whatever reason and then restart before the previous instance releases the sockets, so the second instance can't bind to "in use" sockets. I can't find the reason why nginx tries to restarts.

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is any service using 80 port.

```
netstat -plnt | grep :80
```

This will show u which is running on the 80 port

Comment: I logged in to server when I came to know that nginx is stopped unexpectedly. At that time, nothing is running in 80 and when I started nginx manually, it successfully starts. The problem is nginx stopped unexpectedly and this occured twice.

Comment: Kindly share the error log there may be some info we can get...

Comment: Hariharan. The entire log is shared in question.

Time can be predicted, whenever server stops, it happens around 12:00-12:15 and 00:00-00:15 time.

Now again my server went down today. when checked with `sudo netstat -pentl` only 3000 (node) and 3306 (mysql) are running.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is occurring is because port 80 is currently utilised and it could very well be the last nginx instance which didn't shut down properly.

You could check your nginx config and test before starting nginx service.

It should give successfull output on testing.

Comment: Thanks @Issac for your suggestion. The nginx config is verified with command `sudo nginx -t` which says "syntax is ok" and hence able to start nginx. But the problem is nginx was stopped during "signal process started" and this signal is happening every 12 hours and nginx has stopped 3 times (not every 12 hours)

Unable to findout the reason why nginx has stopped.

Comment: @RamBabu did you figure out what the problem was? Facing similar shutdowns with nginx

Comment: @KhoPhi, after years, the architecture has been changed and we're no more using this now